# adding \ to a string when its key is pressed

Tags: javascript

I'm making a programming typing game which needs to include everything it possibly can that involves special characters. I'm having some trouble with the \ (key code 220) key, I want it (upon its button press) to be added to a string and then show up in the output. Every time the string is split instead of being added to output. Is there any way to prevent this? here is my code:

```js
var out = document.getElementById("output");
var string = "";
var shift = false

document.onkeydown = function(e){
  //detect when the "shift" key is held
  if(e.keyCode == 16) shift = true;
  //just to show that this does work
  if(e.keyCode == 65){
    if(shift){
      string += "A";
    }else{
      string += "a";
    }
  }
  //pressing the / key
  if(e.keyCode == 220){
    if(shift){
      string += "|";
    }else{
      string += "\";
    }
  }
  print();
};

document.onkeyup = function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 16) shift = false;
};
function print(){
  out.innerHTML = string;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="output">press the \ or a key</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** my mistake I mean to put the \ key whos keycode was 220. I was looking off the wrong part of my code.

Comment: There's a syntax error in your code, where `string += "\";` doesn't represent a string containing the single `\ ` character, since the `\ ` actually escapes the closing quote.

Comment: @Aaron I am trying to output the character to the string (which is what all the letter and such go in before they are shown). I want to output the \ key but the syntax error _is_ the problem. I was wondering if there was any way to be able to (in my case) output the \ character and fix the syntax error. If there is then that would be fantastic!

Comment: Yup, escape the escaping character, as suggested in Frank Wisniewski's answer. Prefixing a character with `\ ` escapes it, which means it removes its special meaning and instead uses it as the literal character : with `"\"` the second quote isn't closing your string, it's just a quote character inside your string. However with `"\\"` it's now the `\ ` that is escaped, so it doesn't escape the closing quote anymore, but is itself understood as a literal `\ ` character.

Comment: alright it work! Thank you! @Aaron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can´t test it because i have an german Keyboard Layout...

`string += "\\";`

i think it´s also a way to check e.shiftKey..